# How can I change the default REST validation response from HTML to JSON when using Spring?

Tags: java, json, spring, rest, validation

I'm using a pretty standard REST request that looks like:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/rest/xyz")
public class SomeApiService {

    @RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public SomeSharedObject doSomething(@Validated @RequestBody SomeSharedObject so) {
        ...
        return so;
    }
```

That shared object is a POJO with field-level validations:

```
@NotNull(message = "error.fieldA.notNull")
private String fieldA;
```

The validation works. If I supply a value for fieldA, the request works. If I omit the value for fieldA, I get an validation error. The problem is that this validation error is HTML:

[image]

How can I change this response to JSON?

Comment: Theres a good write up here http://springinpractice.com/2013/10/09/generating-json-error-object-responses-with-spring-web-mvc

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? I believe the current versions do that automatically.

Comment: Not using Spring Boot.

Answer (score 0):

When the validation works, there are exceptions would be throwed. Then the server would find the page which is representing the ***httpstatus(404,400,500 etc.)*** that the server responsed.So you need catch the exception and custom your own response.As springmvc, here are my advices.

1.config your ***applicationContext.xml***.

```
    <context:component-scan base-package="cn.org.citycloud">
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation" expression="org.springframework.stereotype.Controller"/>
        <context:exclude-filter type="annotation"
                                expression="org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice"/>
    </context:component-scan>
```

well, just focus on the ***ControllerAdvice***

2.then custom your own ExceptionHandler. Here the sample code.

```
@ControllerAdvice
public class ApiExceptionHandler {
    @ExceptionHandler(BusinessErrorException.class)
    @ResponseStatus(value = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST)
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorResponse handleBusinessErrorException(BusinessErrorException ex) {
        return new ErrorResponse(ex.getCode(), ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

here, HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST reprented 400.ErrorResponse is your custom response.

Answer (score 0):

In Spring you can use the [ResponseEntity](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/ResponseEntity.html) class:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/doSomething", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public ResponseEntity<SomeSharedObject> doSomething(@Validated @RequestBody SomeSharedObject so) {
    ...
    return new ResponseEntity<>(so, HttpStatus.OK);
}
```